# How to enable a preview in the "Open File - Portal" on Ubuntu Studio 22.04

Tags: files, filemanager, ubuntu-studio, dialog, previews

The previews in Dolphin are working very well, but if I try to open a file from within an application, the "Open File" dialog is missing any previews.

As example: If I try to find a specific picture out of a bunch of several others, I'm lost without a preview.
[image: "Open File dialog"]
There is nothing, even in the preview panel.

Does anyone know, how to enable it?

My system: Ubuntu Studio 22.04 ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fond the answer in another forum:

Go to Dolphin > Configure > Configure Dolphin > General > Previews > Skip previews for remote files above > Set it from ‘No previews’ to e.g. 100 MB.

This works perfectly.
[image]